# Есть ListView. Он заполняется через адаптер. Нужно изменить ширину конкретного элемента

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть ListView. Он заполняется через адаптер. При нажатие на каждый элемент ListView появляется новая активити где выбираем ширину и фон кнопки, на которую нажали. Я передаю данные через синглтон в адаптер .  Не получается изменить ширину элемента ListVIew, кнопка никак не реагирует на setWidth. Фон же через setBackgroundColor успешно изменяется. Подскажите как быть?

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/ColorTextButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/HelpButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:focusable="false"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HelpButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/HelpButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private  int myColor, myWidth;
private String myItem;
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ColorTextButton);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
    TextView textView2= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HelpButton);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    myColor=DataProvider.getInstance().getColor();
    myWidth=DataProvider.getInstance().getWeight();
    myItem=DataProvider.getInstance().getItem();
    String s = values[position];
    System.out.println(s);
    if (s.equals("Sunday")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        if (s.equals(myItem)){
           textView.setWidth(MyWidth);

            textView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);

        }
    }

    return rowView;
}
}
```

ButtonListActivity.java

```
 public class ButtonListActivity extends ListActivity {

 TextView textView;
int Proportion,     BackColor;
String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //  ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    CustomAdapter forData= new CustomAdapter(this,DayOfWeek);
    setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,DayOfWeek));




}



protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    DataProvider.getInstance().putItem(item);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ButtonListActivity.this,SeekBarWork.class);

    startActivity(intent);

  // Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

  }
```

SeekBarWork.java

```
public class SeekBarWork extends  ActionBarActivity implements           SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

RelativeLayout myscreen; // SEEKBAR
SeekBar rsb, gsb, bsb; // SEEKBAR
int red, green, blue,backgroundColor,prop; //SEEKBAR
Button gotoscreen1;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choise_color);
    gotoscreen1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ColorDone);
    myscreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout); //SEEKBAR
    rsb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.RedSeekBar); //SEEKBAR
    gsb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.GreenSeekBar);//SEEKBAR
    bsb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BlueSeekBar); //SEEKBAR
    rsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR
    gsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR
    bsb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //SEEKBAR
    textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

}
public int updatebackground(){  //SEEKBAR
    int colorr;
    red = rsb.getProgress();
    green = gsb.getProgress();
    blue = bsb.getProgress();
    colorr=0xff000000 + red * 0x10000 + green * 0x100 + blue;
    // myscreen.setBackgroundColor(colorr);

    return colorr;
}
public int max(){
    int maxNum;

    if (red>=green) {
        if (red>=blue) maxNum = red; else maxNum=blue;
    } else if (green>=blue) maxNum=green; else maxNum=blue;
    if (maxNum==0) maxNum=1;
    return maxNum;
}
public int min(){
    int minNum;

    if (red<=green) {
        if (red<=blue) minNum = red; else minNum=blue;
    } else if (green<=blue) minNum=green; else minNum=blue;
    if (minNum==0) minNum=1;
    return minNum;
}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    backgroundColor=(updatebackground());




    //    str=Integer.toString(s);
    //     gotoscreen1.setText(str);

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}


public void onEnterButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SeekBarWork.this,ButtonListActivity.class);
    prop=(int)(((min()*100)/max()));
    DataProvider.getInstance().setData(prop,backgroundColor);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо

> textView.setWidth(MyWidth);

использовать `LayoutParams`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = MyWidth;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает!

Comment: @Mihailenko, рад был помочь! Чтобы будущие посетители страницы могли увидеть, что ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его верным, нажав "галочку" слева от тела ответа.

Comment: Юрий, а можете, пожалуйста, подсказать ещё, как сделать, чтобы выбранные фон и ширина оставались для каждого элемента ListView после их выбора, как лучше изменить структуру программы? А то у меня сохраняются параметры только для последней выбранной кнопки, потому что список строится каждый раз заново

Comment: @Mihailenko, судя по всему у вас в `DataProvider` сохраняется всего один элемент. Сделайте так, чтобы данные туда добавлялись, а не заменялись. И в адаптере пробегайте по массиву из провайдера и выделяйте элементы `ListView` по позиции списка. Как-то так.